# ANTLR is not reporting an error when evaluating a string that does not fits my grammar definition

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlr4, antlrworks, antlrv3ide

This is the first time I am working with ANTLR for a project at Imperial College London and until now it has been really useful. I have already defined a simple recursive grammar as follows

```
grammar Hello;      

execution: workflow;

workflow : Task 
         | workflow OPERATOR workflow 
         |'(' workflow OPERATOR workflow ')'                        
         |'(' workflow OPERATOR workflow ')' (OPERATOR workflow)*                        
          ;


Task : 'T' ('0'..'9')+ | 'WF' ('0'..'9')+;

OPERATOR: 'AND' | 'OR'  | 'XOR' |';' ;

WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

to evaluate strings like :

```
T6 ; (T4 AND T7) ; T5 ; ( (WF23 OR WF2) OR (T3 AND WF4) AND T4) AND T5 OR T11
```

and it works perfectly, my problem comes when I try to evaluate an incorrect string like

```
T6 ; (T4 AND T7) ; T5 ; ( (WF23 OR WF2) OR (T3 AND WF4) AND T4) AND (T5;OR() T2)
```

according to my rules after the last AND  the string  "(T5;OR() T2) " is not valid since it doesn't fits with my grammar definition, but when testing this I get the tree for the string

```
   T6 ; (T4 AND T7) ; T5 ; ( (WF23 OR WF2) OR (T3 AND WF4) AND T4)
```

and the last part "(T5;OR() T2) " which is incorrect is simply ignored.

My question is what am I missing, what should I do to get and error saying that 
"(T5;OR() T2) " doesn't fits with my grammar definition, can somebody knows??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lexer happily tokenizes your malformed input, and you gave the parser the instruction to parse a (valid) `execution`. This is what it did. If you want to force the parser to consume the entire token stream, place an `EOF` at the end of the entry point of your grammar:

```antlr
execution: workflow EOF;
```

If you now parse your input:

```java
String source = "T6 ; (T4 AND T7) ; T5 ; ( (WF23 OR WF2) OR (T3 AND WF4) AND T4) AND (T5;OR() T2)";
HelloLexer lexer = new HelloLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(source));
HelloParser parser = new HelloParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
parser.execution();
```

You will get the following output:

```
line 1:72 no viable alternative at input '(T4 AND T7) ; T5 ; ( (WF23 OR WF2) OR (T3 AND WF4) AND T4) AND (T5;OR'
line 1:15 extraneous input ')' expecting {, OPERATOR}
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer you just saved my day. Really !!! Now it works perfectly!!